# Name attribute in a new field as a function of attribute in another field

Tags: arcpy, field-calculator, cursor

I have table with a field containing attribute names in another language (oldname1, oldname2,...). I want to create a new field in which I can add (with field calculator) the translated name of each attribute in my language (newname1,newname1,...).

[image]

I thought the cursor would be the best way to realize this.
The original field is called fieldA and the new field fieldB

I tried with a cursor but my script isn't working. The error is given for line "if row in 'fieldA'= 'oldname1'

```
myTable = ":\\path to table"


cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(myTable, ['fieldA', 'fieldB'])
for row in cursor:
    if row in 'fieldA'= "oldname"
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(myTable, 'fieldB',"newname1")
    elif...
    .....
```

I tried to add cursors for each field as variable before the loop:

```
fieldA= arcpy.da.SearchCursor(myTable, ['fieldA'])
fieldB= arcpy.da.SearchCursor(myTable, ['fieldB'])
```

But it is not helping. I also try to write ['fieldA'] instead of 'fieldA'

Can I create variables for each field and use it in the cursor? or do you have an idea of how I could fix this?

Comment: You're not using DA Cursors according to the examples in the documentation. It wouldn't be wrong to name the objects `fieldAcursor` and `fieldBcursor`, but they are *not* fieldA and fieldB. It's also wrong to mix-n-match CalculateField with cursors, and your indentation and syntax on the `if` are wrong.  Also the `row in` is a syntax error, since row is an array.  And, if you want to update values, you need an UpdateCursor, not a SearchCursor.

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to do. Could you add a screenshot showing part of the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the CalculateField function or an UpdateCursor, to name an attribute in a new field as a function of an attribute in another field. Here are 3 examples:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/"

# example 1 with a dictonary
expression = "getNewName(!OldName!)"
codeblock = """
def getNewName(oldname):
    my_dictionary = {'Paul_old' : 'Paul_new',
                 'James_old' : 'James_new',
                 'Jane_old' : 'Jane_new'}
    return my_dictionary[oldname]"""

arcpy.CalculateField_management("MyTest.shp", "NewName", 
                                expression, "PYTHON", codeblock)

# example 2 with a string manipulation
expression = "getNewName(!OldName!)"
codeblock = """
def getNewName(oldname):
    return oldname.split('_')[0] + '_new'"""

arcpy.CalculateField_management("MyTest.shp", "NewName", 
                                expression, "PYTHON", codeblock)

# exmaple 3 with update cursor

fields = ['OldName', 'NewName']

with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("MyTest.shp", fields) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        # example with a string manipulation, but could be anything
        # index of row correspond to the index of fields variable
        row[1] = row[0].split('_')[0] + '_new'
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```